# Alamofire - NetworkReachabilityManager doesn't work with .notReachable

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an issue with `NetworkReachabilityManager` from `Alamofire`. I tried to test the connection with this example code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

    manager?.listener = { status in

    switch status {

       case .notReachable:
          print("network connection status - lost")
      case .reachable(NetworkReachabilityManager.ConnectionType.ethernetOrWiFi):
          print("network connection status - ethernet/WiFI")
      case .reachable(NetworkReachabilityManager.ConnectionType.wwan):
          print("network connection status - wwan")
      default:
          break
    }
  } 
  manager?.startListening()
}
```

When I tried to turn the wifi off and I received only blank response. No response like such as "network connection status - lost".

But when I tried to turn on the wifi and I received the result "network connection status - ethernet/WiFI" in which is good response. Any idea what is wrong with `.notReachable`? Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem is related to manager instance definition, can you post where you are declaring `let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")` inside a method?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I updated my post. So you can see where is the method. (Keep in mind I could move those code to a different method it doesn't have to be only in viewDidLoad method. If I moved them to a different method then it has same issues like above.)

Comment: declare manager as variable in your UIViewController and then in viewDidLoad initialize that variable, and let me know if solves your issue, I use NetworkReachabilityManager in a singleton class

Comment: @ReinierMelian I declared manager as variable in my UIViewController and so on like what you said. It doesn't work at all. I will try to use NetworkReachabilityManager in a singleton class. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: @ReinierMelian I tried to use NetworkReachabilityManager in a singleton class and it doesn't work. It is very interesting what I discovered something weird about running application. Before I launched the app, I turned off the wifi first and then I launched the app and it gives me a blank response. But if I decided to have wifi on before to launch the app & it gives response but if I turn off wifi while the application is on it shows the response "no connection".  Do you have the same issues from your project? I just wanted to make sure if it is a bug from Alamofire NetworkReachabilityManager.

Comment: I will check my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `Alamofire` "Make sure to remember to retain the manager" so create a manager like this

```
class A: UIViewController{

let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// before start listening you can check 
if (manager?.isReachableOnEthernetOrWiFi == true)
    {
     print("internet is available")
    }
    else
    {
    print("internet is not available")
    }

manager?.startListening()

manager?.listener = { status in

switch status {

   case .notReachable:
      print("network connection status - lost")
  case .reachable(NetworkReachabilityManager.ConnectionType.ethernetOrWiFi):
      print("network connection status - ethernet/WiFI")
  case .reachable(NetworkReachabilityManager.ConnectionType.wwan):
      print("network connection status - wwan")
  default:
      break
           }
    }     

}

}
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work at all. It is very interesting what I discovered something weird about running application. Before I launched the app, I turned off the wifi first and then I launched the app and it gives me a blank response. But if I decided to have wifi on before to launch the app & it gives response but if I turn off wifi while the application is on it shows the response "network connection status - lost". Do you have the same issues from your project? I just wanted to make sure if it is a bug from Alamofire NetworkReachabilityManager.

Comment: i updated my answer, you can check internet connection with `isReachable` property of manager. because  before app launch internet listener is not available that why it give blank response.

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2275 Check this issue is already filed.